# How to fill form from the strings in txt file - python mechanize

Tags: python, mechanize

I have an web app (example.com) for sending email. I want to send email to multiple email addresses from the list, which are stored in mailing_list.txt. For this purpose I used python with mechanize module.

This code seems to work, but emails are not delivering.

```
#!/bin/python
import mechanize

sender = raw_input("Enter sender email : ")
subject = raw_input("Subject : ")
msg = raw_input("Enter message : ")
filename = raw_input("Attachment location e.g. /home/user/test.txt : ")

file_list = []
f = open('/home/user/mailing_list.txt', 'r')

for line in f.xreadlines():
    url = "http://example.com/"    
    file_list.append([line]) 
    br = mechanize.Browser()
    br.set_handle_robots(False)   
    br.set_handle_refresh(False)
    br.open(url)
    br.form = list(br.forms())[0]
    br["from"] = sender
    br["to"] = line
    br["subject"] = subject
    br["msg"] = msg
    br.form.add_file(open(filename,'rb'),'text/txt',filename,name='file') 
    response = br.submit()
    responder = response.code
    print "Code = " + str(responder)
    print "e-mail sent to: " + line
```

Where could be the problem? From responder I am receiving code 200, and as well I am receiving e-mail sent to each email address from the list/file.

```
 print "Code = " + str(responder)
 print "e-mail sent to: " + line
```

Also if I add lines:

```
 print br["to"]
```

or/and

```
print line
```

I am getting the right response. I mean, it prints current email address from the list.

Comment: Might be worth adding that "200" is the code for 'success': "The HTTP 200 OK success status response code indicates that the request has succeeded."

Comment: is this working if you put mail manually on `br["to"] = 'some@email'` ? Maybe you have to remove `\n` form the end of `line`?

Comment: @furas yes it works, if I put email manually.

Comment: so I expect that problem is `\n` at end of lines - `readlines()` doesn't remove it so you try to send to `some@email\n' with `\n` at the end. If there are spaces in file then you can get with spaces in mail.

Comment: @furas yeah I also think it is problem in whitespaces. Because also if I put after print "e-mail sent to: " + line additional text, it write it in secod row. So, there is the whole line of whitespaces after the line. I need to figure out how to remove it.

Comment: `line = line.strip()` removes spaces, tabs, `'\n'` - and it is often command when you read lines from file

Comment: @furas yeap, it works now. Thank you spo much for your help.